Issue with Training YOLOv8 on a Large Dataset with lack of memory and not good enough
I am encountering issues while training the YOLOv8 model on a dataset with 35,000 images and 10,000 classes. I am trying to train the model using images with a resolution of 1280x1280 but facing not enough memory error in my 8xV100 GPUs.
My current parameters:

task=detect
mode=train
model=/home/e/yolov8x.pt
imgsz=1216
val=False
data=/home/e/dataset/small_21/data.yaml
epochs=60
batch=8
name=small_21
exist_ok=True
device=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Are there any specific tips for setting hyperparameters, using data augmentation techniques, or other strategies to improve the model's performance on such a large and complex dataset?
Can I improve memory usage performance?
